# Replace str values in series into np.nan

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following series

```
s = pd.Series({'A':['hey','hey',2,2.14},index=1,2,3,4)
```

I basically want to mask, the series and check if the values are a str if so i want to replace then with np.nan, how could i achieve that?

Wanted result

```
s = pd.Series({'A':[np.nan,np.nan,2,2.14},index=1,2,3,4)
```

I tried this

```
s.mask(isinstance(s,str))
```

But i got the following ValueError: Array conditional must be same shape as self, i am kinda a newb when it comes to these methods would appreciate a explanation on the why

Comment: it doesn't work because `isinstance(s,str)` is not an array/series. It is a `bool` (which is always `False` since `s` is a `pd.Series` object, not a `str` object). In this *particular* case, you can use `pd.to_numeric`

Comment: I see well thank you for the explantion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```py
out = s.mask(s.apply(type).eq(str))
```

```
print(out)

1     NaN
2     NaN
3       2
4    2.14
dtype: object
```

Comment: Really lovely solution thank you

Answer (score 2):

Use `to_numeric` with the `errors="coerce"` parameter.

```
s = pd.to_numeric(s, errors = 'coerce')
Out[73]: 
1     NaN
2     NaN
3    2.00
4    2.14
dtype: float64
```

Comment: What if there are types beyond int and string like datetime?

Answer (score 2):

If you are set on using `mask`, you could try:

```
s = pd.Series(['hey','hey',2,2.14],index=[1,2,3,4])
s.mask(s.apply(isinstance,args = [str]))
print(s)

1     NaN
2     NaN
3       2
4    2.14
dtype: object
```

But as you can see, many roads leading to Rome...

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, You need to create [`pd.Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) like below then use [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) like below.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series(['hey','hey',2,2.14],index=[1,2,3,4])
s = s.apply(lambda x: np.nan if isinstance(x, str) else x)
print(s)
```

---

```
1     NaN
2     NaN
3    2.00
4    2.14
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
s[s.str.match('\D+').fillna(False)] = np.nan
```

But if you are looking to convert all string 'types' not just representations like "1.23" then refer to @Ynjxsjmh's answer.